# Detect if any type of audio if playing in browser

Tags: javascript, html, flash, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming

I need to build a Javascript tracker that will log a user's radio listening session. A website will generally embed their radio streams into many type of HTML elements, such as the video or audio tag.

I need to detect any form of live audio (i.e. radio stream) that is playing on a website's page. Audios have different formats such as mp3, aac, m3u8, etc. Most of the time, websites use the video or audio tag, and these tags are easily retrievable in Javascript. I can also use the paused attribute to acknowledge if it is playing or not.

My problem is to detect audios that use old technologies like Flash. I don't know where to start to handle these cases. Are there some standards regarding Flash? How can I find the Flash's object and detecting if it is playing or not? Can I find its url?

Comment: I highly doubt this is going to be possible.  For example, embed tags for plugins still exist, and I think they just do their own thing outside of the browser.

Comment: You could search HTML source text and see if any embeded SWF files listed. You cannot check if the app is loading or playing an audio stream unless it tells you (that means the SWF creator must put code inside it that will send a JS alert saying so)